# ldap - lock / unlock accounts

Tags: openldap

I want to create account in Ldap, but its need be active only in future FROM date TO date.
I use ppolicy overlay for Ldap. I try use it:
I create account and on creation time I lock it using

pwdAccountLockedTime = NOW.

I set the

pwdLockoutDuration = (FROM - NOW) in seconds

pwdMaxAge = (TO - NOW) in second.

The account was created with right pwdAccountLockedTime, but after pwdLockoutDuration duration expire, the account not unlocked automatically - why? Maybe because I set pwdAccountLockedTime manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't set pwdPolicySubentry attribute as my new entry and Ldap use pwdLockoutDuration from default configuration, not my custom pwdLockoutDuration from my entry.

Comment: So fixing that is the answer?

Comment: yes, I added in attribute pwdPolicySubentry dn of current entity and set needed pwdLockoutDuration

Answer (score -1):

From MSDN i got, once the lockout duration passes, the user is unlocked automatically.

So check whether you got Zero in `lockoutTime`

Add the Lockout-Time attribute to the Lockout-Duration attribute and then compare it with the current time.Zero in Lockout-Duration means the account is locked forever until the administrator unlock it.

copied from msdn site.[click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> This attribute value is only reset when the account is logged onto successfully. This means that this value may be non zero, yet the account is not locked out. To accurately determine if the account is locked out, you must add the Lockout-Duration to this time and compare the result to the current time, accounting for local time zones and daylight savings time.